# Depth-first directory stream in Java 8

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I'd like to traverse a directory structure in Java 8 using the Stream API in depth-first order. The reason for this is that I want to sort the contents in the files according to a timestamp present in each file on a per directory basis. Essentially I'm looking for something similar to [Files#walk](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#walk-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.FileVisitOption...-) but for directories. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Why does it have to be with the stream API?  It's not really designed for recursion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s hard to understand your problem description, most notably, what you actually want to do when you say you want to “sort the contents in the files according to a timestamp present in each file on a per directory basis”.

And when you say you want “something similar to Files#walk but for directories”, it implies that you have a problem with using `Files.walk` with directories, but it’s not clear, what problem you have.

I.e., you can simply list all subdirectories of the current directory like

```
Files.walk(Paths.get("")).filter(Files::isDirectory).forEach(System.out::println);
```

So if that’s not matching your goal, you have to spent more time elaborating your goal.

Comment: As embarrassing as it may sound I actually think this'll do, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Using [StreamEx](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex) is a breeze:

```
File root = new File("someFilePath");
StreamEx.ofTree(root, x -> StreamEx.of(x.listFiles(File::isDirectory)))
    .map(File::getAbsolutePath) // or whathever you need to do with the folder
    .forEach(System.out::println); // the same as previous line
```

Comment: Thanks. I've voted up because it looks like it would work for me but I'd prefer vanilla Java without any additional dependencies so I'm not marking it as resolved.

Comment: Probably, it's not feasible with just plain stream API like `iterate()` or `generate()`. The best bet is probably implementing a sort of a pre-ordered `TreeIterator` and stream it.

Comment: Anyhow, I'd add the `StreamEx` dep. It's ridiculously powerful (see `EntryStream`) and small-sized. It's a life saver.